# Django AJAX asynchrony call on one url

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

I have question about form submit in Django. There are two forms, each form has own number to be inserted in database.

1. Form1 : must insert value 1
2. Form2 : must insert value 2

Both forms are on url `/kategorije/`. When I submit form1, form1 inserts into database with value 1, that is ok. But when I submit form2, form2 insert value 1. Thet is problem, I wanna insert value 2 in database with form2.
My code looks like:

## models.py

```
class CategoryType(models.Model):
    id   = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_id = models.ForeignKey('CategoryType')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

## forms.py

```
class NewCategory(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+', label=_('Naziv kategorije'),
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                {'class': 'form-control ', 'placeholder': 'Naziv kategorije', 'id': 'kategorija'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
        exclude = ('type_id', )



class NewServiceIn(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+', label=_('Naziv kategorije'),
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                                {'class': 'form-control ', 'placeholder': 'Naziv kategorije', 'id': 'kategorija'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
        exclude = ('type_id', )
```

## views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
@csrf_exempt


def CategoryNew(request):
    template = 'category.html'
    user_pk = request.user.id
    org_name = OrganizationInfo.objects.filter(id=user_pk).values('name')[0]

    error = ''
    success = False

    # Forms
    if request.is_ajax():
        form1 = NewCategory(request.POST or None)

        if form1.is_valid():
            a = form1.save(commit=False)
            name = form1.cleaned_data['name']

            if Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name).exists():
                error = Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name).values('name')[0]
            else:
                a.type_id = CategoryType.objects.get(type='products')
                a.save(name)
                success = name
        ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars))

    else:
        form1 = NewCategory()

    if request.is_ajax():
        form2 = NewServiceIn(request.POST or None)
        if form2.is_valid():
            b = form2.save(commit=False)
            name1 = form2.cleaned_data['name1']

            if Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name1).exists():
                error = Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name1).values('name')[0]
            else:
                b.type_id = CategoryType.objects.get(type='services')
                b.save(name1)
                success = name1

        ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars))

    else:
        form2 = NewServiceIn()

    return render_to_response(template, dict(name=org_name, form1=form1, form2=form2),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## ajax.js

```
/*Service*/
$('#service1').on('submit', function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/kategorije/",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        required: true,
        success: function(response) {

            if (!response.success) {
                console.log(response.error.name);
               $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme_ser',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+response.error.name+'</strong> već postoji!</h4><p class="alert-message">Promjenite naziv kategorije.</p><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });
            } else {
                $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme_ser',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+response.success+'</strong> uspješno je kreirana!</h4><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });

            }
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
           $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme_ser',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+rs.responseText+"konj"+'</strong> već postoji!</h4><p class="alert-message">Promjenite naziv kategorije.</p><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Second Ajax service is same, but form id is different.

## template.html

```
<form id ="service1" action="" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modial_header" id="myModalLabel">Dodavanje kategorije usluga</h4>
        <div id ="alertajme_ser" class="panel-alert"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top:10px;">
              {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Naziv usluge<span class="example1">*</span></label>
                {{ form2.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer bottom_modial">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn_modial_main">SPREMI KATEGORIJU</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

If you could give me some advice with this issue. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in forms.py on statements if. But don't know how to make this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything to tell Django that the forms are separate. They both only have a `name` field; there is nothing at all to tell them apart.

A simple solution for this would be to to use the `prefix` parameter to the forms instantiations, so that Django makes the fields unique.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    form1 = NewCategory(request.POST or None, prefix='form1')
    if form1.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    form1 = NewCategory(prefix='form1')

if request.is_ajax():
    form2 = NewServiceIn(request.POST or None, prefix='form2')
    if form2.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    form2 = NewServiceIn(prefix='form2')
```

Answer (score 0):

in views.py,

```
 if request.is_ajax():
        form1 = NewCategory(request.POST or None)

        if form1.is_valid():
            a = form1.save(commit=False)
            name = form1.cleaned_data['name']

            if Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name).exists():
                error = Category.objects.filter(name__exact=name).values('name')[0]
            else:
                a.type_id = CategoryType.objects.get(type='products')
                a.save(name)
                success = name
        ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars))
```

will always return if request is ajax, even if it was supposed to be for the form2. I think you meant to tabulate the last two lines an additional time, so they only get submitted if form1 is valid.

Comment: Thank you for opinion, but how to make it works. @julius